# How to create separate volumes for each container in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I have created a `docker` image for which I want to run multiple containers. This docker image is dependent on few things which will remain same for all the containers but the only difference will be configuration of the containers.

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    s1:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/s1config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g

    s2:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/s2config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/CVAI:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g
```

In the above file, you can see that I am giving `s1config` and `s2config` for `s1` `s2` containers but rest of the things remains same and this is why `/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI` volume is same for both the containers. Due to this, docker is sharing the volume between both the containers and thus all the data is mixing between containers and not getting separated.

**Is there any way we can separate the volumes between multiple containers.?** I do not want to create multiple dockers for this. Please help. Thanks

**EDIT**

Updated docker-compose file :

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    s1:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/s1/configs/s1config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/s1:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g

    s2:
        image: testdockerimg:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/andrew/Documents/s2/configs/s2config.json:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/configs/config.json
            - /home/andrew/Documents/s2:/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 2g
```

Comment: Move your variable container specific data out of `/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI` into a separate volume.

Comment: @Henry As I said that I am using same docker image, and the starting point in the docker file is `/home/andrew/Documents/CVAI/file.py`. If I make volume as container specific then containers will not run because the path have changed.

Comment: The path inside the container remains the same. You just mount two different external volumes. This is like you did with s1config and s2config

Comment: @Henry I am unable to understand. You mean to say that on my host system, I should have two different volumes for s1 s2 and in the container it will remain same.?

Comment: Yes, that's how volume mounts work.

Comment: @Henry Thanks I will try this and will get back to you

Comment: You can do multi layer build in Dockerfile and use that Dockerfile in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Can you please explain more on multi layer build.?

Comment: @Henry As per your suggestion, I have created `s1` `s2` dir on host and its now working fine. If you can answer, I will accept and close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the host each container should have its own volume. They can be mounted in the container at the same path. Each container can use the same image and will see its dedicated volume on the host under the same name.